# Retrieving from $_GET

Tags: php, get

My code:

```
<?php
echo "lol";
$gotid = $_GET["id"];
echo $gotid;
?>
```

The problem is that it won't echo the id that I gave in the link http://runninbrecht.be/adminText.php?Id=500. There it should say: lol500

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an upper-case "I" in the URL, but a lower-case "i" in the code:
http://runninbrecht.be/adminText.php?id=500

Also: [Be careful with user input from GET parameters](http://runninbrecht.be/adminText.php?id=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22I%20hacked%20you!%22);window.location.href='http://google.com/?q=php%20security%20get%20parameters';%3C/script%3E)

Comment: thanks! I thought i checked it!

Answer (score 0):

Strings in PHP are case-sensitive. You're passing `Id=500`, with a capital I in the URL, but accessing `$_GET["id"]`, with a lower case i in the code.

Either change the URL to use a lowercase i ( http://runninbrecht.be/adminText.php?id=500), or use an uppercase I in the code (`$gotid = $_GET["Id"]`).

Comment: thanks! I thought i checked it!

Answer (score 0):

its because you wrote "Id" with capital i in url and you are trying to get it by key "id" with (i not I), php is case sensitive so just check this url:

http://runninbrecht.be/adminText.php?id=500

Comment: thanks! I thought i checked it!